# Laravel's bcrypt changes passwords, but then I cannot log in

Tags: laravel, bcrypt

I have a PHP/Laravel script that allows user to change his password:

```
$obj_user->password = bcrypt($post['password']);
```

But once the password is changed, user cannot log back in with the new password.
I am using Laravel 5.3, and I don't get any warnings when I use bcrypt, so I am not sure of what's going on.

Comment: Can they still log in with the old password?.

Comment: Do you save the updated model to the database?

Comment: yes, I saved it. Could it be possible that maybe updated_at  is not changing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all, look at my code:

```
$obj_user = User::find($user_data['id']);
$obj_user->password = $post['password'];//Hash::make($post['password']);   
$obj_user->save();
```

Notice two things:  (1) I am using a Laravel model to get the user's data. (2) And Hash::make is grayed out. I am no longer using it yet I was able to encrypt the password anyhow.

This issue has affected Laravel users in the past. Inside the User model, I have this:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{ $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password); }
```

This is a Laravel mutator. When I use the save() method on the model the mutator activates and encrypts the password. Therefore, my problem was that I was encrypting my password twice. Laravel models with mutators may cause problems if the programmer is not aware of them.